# Visual Studio 2008 Case Expression using null

Tags: sql

I'm trying to right a report that lets a user select either 'all values including null' or 'all values excluding null'.  I placed a case expression in the where section.  It doesn't work correctly for two reasons:

- I can't pull the values of null and is not null at the same time.
- In both cases it ends up pulling all values including null for the first one and only null values for the second.

Where

```
((CASE WHEN @nullvalue = 1 THEN check_rtn_void_dte end is not null) OR (CASE WHEN @nullvalue = 2 THEN check_rtn_void_dte end is null))
```

Is there a operator I can use that will pull null and is not null in one statement?  Also, why is the first case pulling all data including null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would be simpler...

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (@nullvalue = 2 OR check_rtn_void_dte IS NOT NULL)
```

That should pull out all results if @nullvalue = 2, or only non-NULL values if @nullvalue is something else.

Comment: That worked wonderfully and is super simple I was beating my head against the desk for 10hrs.  Thank you, you are a genius!

Comment: Is there a way to have it also display NULL only?  Something like WHERE (@nullvalue = 2 OR 3 IS NULL OR check_rtn_void_dte IS NOT NULL)

Comment: This should do it.  When @nullvalue is 1, non-null values are returned.  When @nullvalue is 2, all values are returned.  When @nullvalue is 3, null values are returned.  `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (@nullvalue = 2 OR (@nullvalue = 3 AND check_rtn_void_dte IS NULL) OR (@nullvalue = 1 AND check_rtn_void_dte IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: That did it! I'm so glad your able to wrap your head around null values.  Thank you again